# Unable to open Schema browser. Username , password or security token reset error wen launching eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have changed my salesforce password/security token recently and getting the error : Unable to open schema browser error when i login to eclipse. How do I solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to Project > Properties > Force.com, and enter your updated password and security token.